# How to find the orthogonal projection of $y$ on $V^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let be

$ u_1=\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
5\\
-1 
\end{bmatrix}, u_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
1\\
1 
\end{bmatrix},y=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
3 
\end{bmatrix}$

I'm looking for the projection of $y$ on $V^\perp$, knowing that $V$ is generated by $S=\{u_1,u_2\}$.*

I did the projection of $proj_V(y)$:
\begin{align*}
proj_V(y)&=\frac{<y.u_1>}{||u_1||^2}u_1+\frac{<y.u_2>}{||u _2||^2}u_2\\
&=\frac{3}{10}u_1+\frac{1}{2}u_2
\end{align*}

But I don't know how to find the projection of $y$ on $V^\perp$.
Do you have any hint? I don't perefectly understand what $V^\perp$ is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\operatorname{proj}_V(y)$ is the element of $V$ that is closest to $y.$ $V^\perp$ is the set of all vectors $v$ such that $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for all $u\in V$, or (geometrically) the set of vectors that are orthogonal to every $V$-vector. Now, consider $y-\operatorname{proj}_V(y).$

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply find a (nonzero) vector in $V ^\bot$ (how?), and then calculate the orthogonal projection of y onto this vector. Exercise:prove that the two methods are equivalent(you can think to the orthogonal decomposition of a vector onto a given direction).